# Экстраполяция синуса и косинуса

Tags: машинное-обучение, численные-методы

Только что закончилось одно мини-соревнование по машинному обучению, и сейчас я хочу узнать, как решается одна задача оттуда.

Горизонтальные координаты парашютиста от времени имеют следующий вид: `x = a * cos(b * t) + шум`, `y = b * sin(a * t) + шум`. Даны координаты парашютиста в первую тысячу секунд: `t = 0 .. 999`. Необходимо спрогнозировать координаты парашютиста в следующую тысячу секунд: `t = 1000 .. 1999`. Никаких уточнений по метрике и по значениям шума не давалось, требовали просто сделать прогноз максимально точным.

Основную проблему у меня вызвала зависимость двух этих функций от одних и тех же параметров. Я аппроксимизировал каждую из них по отдельности, и поэтому итоговая точность у меня очень и очень хромала.

Есть ли какие-то стандартные методы для решения такой задачи? Она выглядит, на самом деле, очень базово, и я предполагаю, что мне банально не хватает опыта понять, что нужно сделать.

Comment: Тут метод наименьших квадратов даже без градиентного спуска замечательно ложится... хотя надо расписать, может все таки нужен градиентный будет из-за тригонометрической функции (но ее начинка простая, так что...) :)

Comment: @Zhihar а как его можно для двух функций одновременно считать? Или можно просто минимизировать `sum((y - sin)^2 + (y - cos)^2)`?

Comment: у вас есть теоретическая точка (x0, y0) и экспериментальная (x1, y1) - считайте между ними квадрат расстояния - сумма для 1000 точек этих квадратов должна быть минимальна - вот и все, пока на бумаге записал вроде все таки градиентный спуск потребуется все таки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

чуть более подробно - чтобы я сделал:

я использовал бы **метод наименьших квадратов**, а коэффициенты искал бы с помощью **градиентного спуска** (любого алгоритма, проблема оврагов не думаю, что сильная будет)

т.е. есть теоретические координаты

```
x0(t) = a * cos(b * t), 
y0(t) = b * sin(a * t)
```

и есть экспериментальные точки `x(t), y(t)`

расстояние между экспериментальной и теоретической точками соответственно:

```
s(t) = (x0(t) - x(t))^2 + (y0(t) - y1(t))
```

в методе наименьших квадратов требуется найти такие параметры `a, b` для которых

```
sum s(t) t=0..1000 -> min
```

в некоторых случаях удаётся "схалявить", если теоретические формулы нормально дифференцируются (хотя бы 1 параметр можно вычислить теоретически), в данном случае это не очень получается, поскольку все таки параметры внутри тригонометрических функций находятся

так что придется применять градиентный спуск и аккуратненько спускаться от `a_start` и `b_start` до `a_min` и `b_min` при которых указанная выше сумма будет минимальной

дешево и сердито (и точность неплохая будет и скорость вычислений хорошая)

**P.S.**

на счёт шума в формуле не очень понял, возможно придется искать не 2, а 4 параметра:

```
x0(t) = a * cos(b * t) + m, 
y0(t) = b * sin(a * t) + n
```

но вроде как я понял шум как раз около 0 ходит, а не около некоторых параметров `m, n`

Comment: Спасибо, оказалось довольно просто)